# hiding comments in matlab's editor

Tags: matlab, comments

Is there a simple way to hide the comments while you're writing your code in matlab's editor?
I have too many comments and they really get on my nerves sometimes.
I did a little search and was surprised to find nothing on this simple issue!
Thank you in advance

Comment: Why would you write comments that annoy you in the first place? If they aren't needed to understand the code, then what are they doing there?

Comment: I need the comments because at the moment I know what I'm doing but 6 months from now, I'll probably have forgotten some parts and the comments will help me remember. Also other members of my group need to understand what the code is doing, so the comments are really necessary!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution would be to use **block comments**

```
%{ 
Hello World
%}
```

and **code folding** (Preferences > Editor > Code folding)

[image]

And with right-click on the editor window you can **"Fold all"** then.
If you don't want to get your functions and loops folded as well, uncheck that in the preferences.

---

I'm afraid there is no way in the Matlab Editor to hide all commented lines in general. You will need alternative editors like Notepad++ to do that.

Comment: This will help me alot. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[thewaywewalk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28298179/3871918) is probably what you were looking for, but for the sake of completeness: Even without block comments you can always fold the first comment in a function definition.

Before:
[image: Unfolded]
After:

[image: Folded]

Comment: This actually helps since now I'll explain my variables in the function definition with more ease. Thanks for the help.